# mongodb aggregate group by category

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am new in using MongoDB's aggregation framework and here I have below a schema:

```
var bookSoldSchema = new Schema({
   buyer:{
      type: Number
   }
   book: {         
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book'
   } 
});

 var bookSchema = new Schema({
     bookName: { type: String },
     categories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BookCategory'}],
 })
```

Each book has multiple categories, I would like to show the top 5 best seller categories and each category I need show top 3 books which where sold most, and I also need show the category name, the results which I need is:

```
[
      {
        categoryId: xxx,
        categoryName:xxx,
        top3books:[
           {bookId:xxx, bookName:xxx},
           {bookId:xxx, bookName:xxx},
           {bookId:xxx, bookName:xxx},
        ]
     },
     {
       categoryId: xxx,
       categoryName:xxx,
       top3books:[
          {bookId:xxx, bookName:xxx},
          {bookId:xxx, bookName:xxx},
          {bookId:xxx, bookName:xxx},
       ]
    }
]
```

How can I go about this in MongoDB?

Comment: Could you please add sample doc for testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following aggregation pipeline which assumes you have a model `BookSold` that uses the `bookSoldSchema` above, `books` and `bookcategories` underlying collections:

```
BookSold.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "books",
            "localField": "book",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "book_join"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$book_join" },
    { "$unwind": "$book_join.categories" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "bookcategories",
            "localField": "book_join.categories",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "categories"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$categories" },
    { "$sort": { "categories.name": 1, "buyer": -1 } }, 
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$categories.name",
            "categoryId": { "$first": "$categories._id" },
            "buyer": { "$first": "$buyer" },
            "books": { 
                "$push": { 
                    "bookId": "$book_join._id", 
                    "bookName": "$book_join.bookName" 
                } 
            }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "buyer": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 5 },
    {
       "$project": {
           "_id": 0,
           "categoryId": 1,
           "categoryName": "$_id",
           "top3books": { "$slice": [ "$books", 3 ] }
       }
    }
], function(err, result) {
    if (err) handleError(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much @chridam, the top 3 books of category is not first 3 book, I would like to get top 3 most sold in that category, it means the top count(bookId) of that category. Could you help that?